# How to add a menu item from my custom Drupal 7-module

Tags: php, menu, drupal-7, hook-menu

with my custom drupal-module i'm trying to insert add a menu-item to a menu using `hook_menu()`. 
It should display the user-name linked to the user-profile.
(My task could be similar to [Add menu item/link to Drupal menu (programatically?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386456/add-menu-item-link-to-drupal-menu-programatically).)

[Edit:] I tried to solve the task with the following, but it could be, that its the wrong way to do it..

```php
function mymodule_view_user_page()
{  
  global $user;
  if ($user->uid != 0) {
    /*$items = array(
      'link_path'   => drupal_get_normal_path('user'),
      'link_title'  => 'Account',
      'menu_name'   => 'main-menu',
      'weight'      => 8,
    );*/

    $items['user'] = array(
      'title'           => 'Page name',
      'description'     => t('Account'),
      'menu_name'       => 'main-menu',
      'weight'          => 8,
      'access callback' => TRUE,
      'page callback'   => 'mymodule_view_user_page',
      'access arguments' => array('view own profile'), // permission
      'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,

    );
    return $items;
  }
}

function mymodule_view_user_page_view_user_page()
{
  drupal_goto('user');
}
```

With the code above there is nothing showing up, but also no errors..

I probably don't want to use an `page callback` since that page already exists properly but i'm unsure about not setting it.

The `hook_menu()` documentation-page [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) is really extensive but it seems i'm not understanding it correct and beginning to loose hairs over it..

Thank you for hints!
PP

Comment: I think i would like to know a method to add a link to a path inside of my custom module. - The code above is how i tried to solve the problem..

Answer (score 4):

Drupal hooks are based on a naming convention, if the hook is called `hook_menu()` and your module is called `mymodule` then the function you need to implement is called `mymodule_menu()`. The code would look like this:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['user'] = array(
    'title'           => 'Page name',
    'description'     => t('Account'),
    'menu_name'       => 'main-menu',
    'weight'          => 8,
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'page callback'   => 'drupal_goto',
    'page arguments' => array('user'),
    'access arguments' => array('view own profile'), // permission
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

However, the path `user` is already declared in the system so what you're doing will create all sorts of problems. What you want to do instead is use [`hook_menu_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) and change the `menu_name` for the already existing path:

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['user']['menu_name'] = 'main-menu';
}
```

Doing it this way you won't need to provide your own page callback as the standard `user` path will just deliver the normal page. The only difference is that once you've cleared Drupal's caches the link to the account should appear in the main menu.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
- Since your solution is only for modifing the menu-item for this path, do you think there is the possibility to add a custom menu item to the menu? Like `user/uid/edit`..